# Get texturecoordinates from shader to CPU-side

Tags: android, glsl, textures, opengl-es-2.0

I am looking for a solution to fetch the texturecoords that is stored on the GPU-side.

that is the attribute (in) - the texturecoords that are passed in to the shader
through a floatbuffer

```
  mCubeTextureCoordinates.position(0);
  GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mTextureCoordinateHandle, GLfields.TEXTURE_COORD_DATASIZE, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            0, mCubeTextureCoordinates);
```

in glsl-program

```
attribute vec2 a_TexCoordinate;
```

Could I fetch the vec2-data on the cpu-side at some stage like ..

```
int textAttr = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_TexCoordinate");

GLES20.glGetFloatv(textAttr, xy, 0);
```

where xy is a float-vector (float[] xy = new ...)

Just a guess, the array is not filled with any data according to the debugger
but I guess you get the point - fetch the texturecoord-vector from the GPU

Answer (score 1):

You are using `glVertexAttribPointer` with *client-side vertex arrays*. To my knowledge, this does not provide a way to read back the data.

However, this usage mode has been deprecated for a long time in favor of *vertex buffer objects* (and *vertex array objects*). Roughly, the usage pattern is:

- Create a VBO (this allocates memory on the GPU)
- Fill the VBO with vertex data
- Use [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) and `glEnableVertexAttribArray` to bind the VBO data to a vertex attribute

A VBO does allow reading its contents via `glGetBufferSubData`.

Have a look at these other questions for more information:

- [OpenGL ES 2 on Android: how to use VBOs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25053786/opengl-es-2-on-android-how-to-use-vbos)
- [Rendering in opengl 3.1+ without VBO using client side vertex array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178601/rendering-in-opengl-3-1-without-vbo-using-client-side-vertex-array)

Also, [`getFloatv` and friends](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGet.xhtml) is used to get OpenGL parameter values (like the current blend mode), not vertex attribute values.

Comment: Thanks I'´ve used VBO before - just came back to OpenGL after a longer break - I´ll look into this and may accept the answer then. thanks!!!